# How to remove warning message that appears when the src is not defined with pyQgis?

Tags: pyqgis, coordinate-system

I am currently learning to use PyQGIS, when loading a shapefile I get a warning message "The SRC is not defined", but I do not know what to do to prevent that message from appearing.

[image: Warning message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the message gone when you load your layer, you could use:

```
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets().
```

Also, if you go to `Settings > Options > CRS > CRS for new layers`, you could choose which CRS to use for new layers or those without a CRS. This should also avoid the pop-up message from appearing.

Finally, it could save you some hassle if you ensure that your shapefile contains a **.prj** file associated with it.